# Type mismatch: cannot convert from FragmentOne to Fragment when create FragmentOne in seperate class?

Tags: android, android-fragments

when i Fragment fr=new FragmentOne(); it gives me error if i create FragmentOne() class in same activity than it will not give error but when i create FragmentOne() out side of activity than it will gives me error

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the
     * navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in
     * {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        Fragment fr=new FragmentOne();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fr).commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments



    }
```

Comment: Does your parent fragment & child fragment has the same packages imported - android.app.Fragment (or) android.support.v4.app.Fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess then the problem was with your package imports which by now you should have figured it out. Either use  android.app.Fragment (or) android.support.v4.app.Fragment based on your app requirements :-)

Comment: Thanks dude great problem solving skills :)